# Why Did My Moodle Due Dates Change

Tags: moodle

We have due dates set on most of our assignments to 11:55pm. We just noticed that all of our due dates changed to 7:55pm on all assignments (the dates stayed the same, just the time changed). This happened in all of our courses, so it is not isolated to a single course.

So why the four hour change? I double checked the server time and that is correct, my profile time is set to be correct as well. So any idea how or why this could be happening? We obviously don't want it to happen.

We are using Moodle 2.8.1

Comment: Did the server or user timezone change? Server timezone : https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Location#Default_timezone User timezone : https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Update_profile#General

Comment: Nope, the server and user timezone are still the same, both set to New York.